# i cannot declare new property in request object of express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, backend, ts-node

I'm trying to attach the new property to the request object in typescript.
this is the code :

```
import { request, Request, response, Response } from "express";

((req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log(req.user);
})(request, response)
```

i'm declaring like this :

```
declare global {
   namespace Express {
      interface Request {
         user: string;
      }
   }
}
```

and then I'm running it with ts-node. result is :

```
/home/mahdi/Desktop/learn-stuf/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:843
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
x.ts:9:21 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

9     console.log(req.user);
                      ~~~~

    at createTSError (/home/mahdi/Desktop/learn-stuf/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:843:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/mahdi/Desktop/learn-stuf/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:847:19)
    at getOutput (/home/mahdi/Desktop/learn-stuf/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1057:36)
    at Object.compile (/home/mahdi/Desktop/learn-stuf/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1411:41)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/mahdi/Desktop/learn-stuf/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1596:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/mahdi/Desktop/learn-stuf/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1600:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2339 ]
}
```

I tested too many answers of sites, but one of them did not work. please help.

Comment: You should use ```export``` keyword before interface.

Comment: @Zahid Çakıcı
i do but still not works

Comment: Did you configured tsconfig.json ?

Comment: @ZahidÇakıcı
i set this in tsconfig typeRoots": [
      "./node_module/@types",
      "./src/declare"
    ],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, I think your declare file got some problems.
   edit the file like

```
export {}

declare global {
   namespace Express {
      interface Request {
         user: string;
      }
   }
}
```

or

```
namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user?: string
  }
}
```

2. add directory that contains the declare file in `tsconfig`. Since I usually name it `express.d.ts` and place in `src/types` folder, in my case, `tsconfig.json` will be edited like this

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["src/types"],
  }
}
```

3. lastly, also add ts-node configuration in `tsconfig.json`. (not in `compilerOptions`)

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for [@types/express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express) ?

You can also fix it with [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) :

```
function endpoint (req: Request, res: Response & {user: string;}) {
  console.log(req.user);
}
```

But maybe you are looking for `req.body.user`, type `Response<{user: string;}>` ?